# why jquery loads with second refresh from functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am converting an html template to WordPress. I use `wp_enqueue_script()` from `functions.php` page. But the .js files loads after second refresh of the page. I have progress bar and top (link to top of the page) on home page which are not working. Please help

I tried `wp_deregister_script('jquery');` but it also not working

```
function loadjs(){
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script('juery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('juery');
wp_register_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('custom');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadjs');
```

progress bar work after second refresh and top function not working

Comment: Any errors thrown? Personally doubt issue has to do with enqueing scripts and something else is different on refresh

Comment: Why deregister and re-register jQuery? Why not just leave jQuery alone and instead specify jQuery as a dependency for your script, ex: wp_enqueue_script('custom', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/js/custom.js', array('jquery'), null, true); (Also, is that a typo in your code, 'juery'?)

Comment: I tried both ways, (also without deregister) but nothing working. when I am on home page, no jquery or custom.js is loaded, then once i refresh it, jquery loads and custom.js show this error (top is undefined)

Comment: Thanks for reply emmzee, I type juery to be unique name as i want to jquery-3.2.1.min.js to connect. I try even only jquery to be connect online from wordpress but both loading after second refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replying everyone, I just figure out the solution. This was due to jquery and solved with a plugin called 'jquery updater'.